# MSM and Store Product Price isn't saving

Tags: expresso-store

I have a MSM install.

Whenever I save an entry for 25.00 it saves as 2500. The other issue is the price for Product Options changes to +5 instead of 5.00

Is this a settings configuration for store? It currently has 2 decimal places etc

Currently I have store installed on the subdomain store.domain.com and the channel is in the www.domain.com because I will need to share the channel info.

Answer (score 1):

Just to explain why this happens.

This will occur if you have Store installed on one site in MSM and use the fieldtype in another Site. The fieldtype doesn't have any settings for that site and no configuration options like decimal points, etc exist. Store requires that it be installed on each installation of an MSM site.

Answer (score 0):

As Brad mentioned you can not share the fields across sites.

If you need to share information across sites the easiest way to do that is to set up a new channel on the sub-domain with a playa/relationship field and a Store field so you can enter the product info on the sub-domain and then relate the entry to the product on the main site to pull in all of the other custom field data.

I would also recommend heading over to their [feature request](https://www.exp-resso.com/support/feature-requests) page and vote for making Store MSM aware.

Comment: I assumed the MSM Compatible on Devot-ee meant that it was compatible 'like' MSM in that it can share the data. Duplicating data or having two stores or three just isn't a good solution for an MSM site in my opinion as that sort of defeats the purpose. I've changed the plan now for this project. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Was just reading this thread as part of researching Exp Store, and wondering if you could clarify something. By relating products on the subdomain via a playa/relationship field to channel entries on the main domain, will it be possible to easily display product info like price on the main domain? (i.e. info stored in the Store field type?) Or do you only recommend this method for accessing other non-Store fields in the product channel entry?

Comment: You would want to create a Store field for each site in the MSM install to handle Store specific things like price, weight, modifiers. But you shouldn't have a problem getting any non-store data from other custom fields on a MSM site.